# What is doing kill() in the examples code

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I am reading the UVM examples, shipped with UVM package, and have one question from
*simple/basci_examples/pkg/test.v*

Following lines exist there:

```
  initial begin
    set_config_int("mu.*", "data", 101);
    set_config_string("mu.*", "str", "hi");
    set_config_int("mu.l1", "data", 55);
    set_config_object("mu.*", "obj", bar);
    mu.print_config_settings("", null, 1);
    uvm_default_printer = uvm_default_tree_printer;
    mu.print();
    factory.print(1);
    run_test();
    mu.print();
  end
  initial
    #5 mu.l1.kill(); // <- this line meaning
endmodule
```

Can someone please explain what is doing `#5 mu.l1.kill();` line?

Thanks
Hayk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `uvm_component::kill()` method has been removed from the UVM 1.2 and later. It was leftover from the OVM (the predecessor to the UVM), and even then [the documentation](https://verificationacademy.com/verification-methodology-reference/ovmworld/docs_2.1.1/html/files/base/ovm_component-svh.html#ovm_component.run) recommended against using kill().

Also, the examples released with the UVM are not very good for learning the UVM. They are mostly quick tests used by the UVM developers to check features. The README.txt file even says this. A much better place is https://verificationacademy.com/cookbook/uvm